# Why cant I run bin/behat?

Tags: php, terminal, composer-php, behat

I am trying to run behat on my vendor folder. I have installed composer globally, have installed the behat package, but every time I run bin/behat I keep getting this message from composer

```
You must set up the project dependencies, run the following commands:
curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php
php composer.phar install
```

I am not sure how to fix this. I see the files are in the vendor folder, and when I type "composer" on the terminal, I see the manual.

If anyone can help me resolve this I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: you say "have installed the behat package", so does that mean you have run `composer install` from the root of the project folder?

Comment: @JeffPuckettII Yes I did it from the root project folder

Comment: You have many examples here http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/posts/behat How it is installed, prepared, used, run etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible problems leading to this situation:

1. Make sure that `composer` is installed in your `$PATH`. That is, running `composer` at a command prompt should work, and you shouldn't need to run an explicit path like `~/Downloads/composer.phar`
2. Execute the `composer install` instruction as the error message suggests. A common error is the message

   > Mcrypt PHP extension required

   in which case you need to install the specified extension. For example, `brew install php56-mcrypt` on a Mac or `sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt` on Ubuntu.